# jQuery click() not working in mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, click

```
<button class="proceed">
    <div class="text-sm-bold clr-white" onclick="proceedBook()">PROCEED FOR BOOKING</div>
</button>
<button id="hid-cb" hidden type="submit" class="proceed-btn" name="conform-booking">PROCEED FOR BOOKING</button>

const proceedBook= ()=>{$("#hid-cb").click()}
```

`$("#hid-cb").click()` not work in mobile

instead i use jQuery vclick

```
const proceedBook= ()=>{$("#hid-cb").vclick()}
```

> error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).vclick is not a function

Comment: where is `$("#hid-cb")` element? I am unable to see in your code.

Comment: also `const proceedBook= ()=>{$("#hid-cb").click()}` needs to be `function proceedBook(){$("#hid-cb").trigger('click');}`

Comment: for me, your code working after the change I mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/7hzq3vye/

Answer (score 0):

```
const proceedBook = () => {
$("#hid-cb").trigger('click');
}
```

This will trigger the 'click' event on the hidden button when the proceedBook() function is called.

For mobile compatibility, ensure that your mobile environment supports the events you're using. Sometimes, certain events might behave differently on mobile browsers, and you may need to use touch events or other mobile-specific events.

```
const proceedBook = () => {
// Check for mobile and trigger appropriate event
if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $("#hid-cb").trigger('touchstart'); // Use touchstart for mobile
} else {
    $("#hid-cb").trigger('click'); // Use click for non-mobile
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const proceedBook = () => {
$("#hid-cb").trigger('click');
}

const proceedBook = () => {
$("#hid-cb").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**